# Accept JSON LD java api

Tags: java, json, jax-rs, json-ld

I am using the jax-rs library to build an api for my application. It is simply based on JSON. Now I have a client who sents JSON-LD . How can I accept this format?
 Usually my method looks like this:

```
@Path("/create")
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public UserId create_account(User user){
    //smth
}
```

But in order to receive a jsonld format I don't know how to handle it and how to build a java model that represents it so that the library maps it correctly.

Comment: Look for a third party Jackson module (like [this one](https://github.com/io-informatics/jackson-jsonld)) and [configure it with Jackson in a ContextResolver](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson). This is assuming you're using Jackson as your JSON provider.

Answer (score 0):

For the Content-Type you can continue using the application/json type, I believe.

For parsing, there is a library https://github.com/jsonld-java/jsonld-java which you may find useful.